# Default behavior of align environment regarding flush and white space

Tags: align, alignat

I have the following code

```
\begin{matrix}
& u & = u_{-\frac{1}{2}} + u_0 \\
& v_0 \cdot u & = v_0 \cdot u_{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
& f\partial^{[1]} - \partial^{[0]} & = -\frac{1}{2} u_{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
\therefore & w_{-\frac{1}{2}} & = -2 f \partial^{[1]} + 2 \partial^{[0]}
\end{matrix}
```

[image]

I want the equals signs to be aligned. So, I try the alignment environment instead:

```
\begin{align*}
& u & = u_{-\frac{1}{2}} + u_0 \\
& v_0 \cdot u & = v_0 \cdot u_{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
& f\partial^{[1]} - \partial^{[0]} & = -\frac{1}{2} u_{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
\therefore & w_{-\frac{1}{2}} & = -2 f \partial^{[1]} + 2 \partial^{[0]}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

I don't know why it aligns flush right rather than flush left for the third column, but I know this tends to fix it:

```
\begin{align*}
& u && = u_{-\frac{1}{2}} + u_0 \\
& v_0 \cdot u && = v_0 \cdot u_{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
& f\partial^{[1]} - \partial^{[0]} && = -\frac{1}{2} u_{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
\therefore & w_{-\frac{1}{2}} && = -2 f \partial^{[1]} + 2 \partial^{[0]}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

All right. What if I use alignat instead of align?

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
& u && = u_{-\frac{1}{2}} + u_0 \\
& v_0 \cdot u && = v_0 \cdot u_{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
& f\partial^{[1]} - \partial^{[0]} && = -\frac{1}{2} u_{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
\therefore & w_{-\frac{1}{2}} && = -2 f \partial^{[1]} + 2 \partial^{[0]}
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Awesome.

My questions: Why does the align environment behave the way it does with single and double column separators? Is it actually alternating flush left/right in some weird way, or am I mistaking it for something else? Is there some reason align can't/shouldn't minimize wasteful horizontal white space on its own? What is the pattern to where it decides to add that space?

Comment: Why are you using `&&` before the `=` symbols?

Comment: it alternates right and left why do you have & at the start of every row? there are examples of all these layouts in the amsmath guide. texdoc amsmath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My main recommendation to you would be to peruse section 3, "Displayed equations", of the user guide of the [amsmath package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to learn more about the multi-row display-math environments provided by this package.

If there's but a single alignment point per row, I suggest you use an `align*` environment with a single alignment point indicator, `&`, per row. To create a bit of horizontal spacing after `\therefore` in row 4, just insert instructions such as `\qquad\qquad` or `\hspace{15mm}`.

If it's really important to you to remove any semblance of visual formatting activity (see the `\qquad\qquad` or `\hspace{15mm}` instruction in the preceding paragraph) from your code, use an `{alignat*}{2}` environment, insert `&&` at the start of rows 1 thru 3, and replace `\therefore \hspace{15mm}` with `\therefore &\quad&` at the start of row 4. Otherwise, keep the `align*` setup of the preceding paragraph.

Unless your document is very hard pressed for vertical space, do also consider replacing the in-line symbol `\therefore` with the *word* "Therefore", on a text line of its own; see the third example below for how this may be implemented. Your readers may truly appreciate you making an effor to provide such an easy-to-spot sign post.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \shortintertext macro; load amsmath package automatically
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for \therefore macro
\newcommand\onehalf{\smash[t]{-\frac{1}{2}}} % \smash[t] for a smaller vertical offset

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  u & = u_{\onehalf} + u_0 \\
  v_0 \cdot u & = v_0 \cdot u_{\onehalf} \\
  f\partial^{[1]} - \partial^{[0]} & = -\tfrac{1}{2} u_{\onehalf} \\
  \therefore \hspace{15mm} 
  w_{\onehalf} & = -2 f \partial^{[1]} + 2 \partial^{[0]}
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &&  u & = u_{\onehalf} + u_0 \\
  &&  v_0 \cdot u & = v_0 \cdot u_{\onehalf} \\
  &&  f\partial^{[1]} - \partial^{[0]} & = -\tfrac{1}{2} u_{\onehalf} \\
  \therefore &\quad& 
      w_{\onehalf} & = -2 f \partial^{[1]} + 2 \partial^{[0]}
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
  u & = u_{\onehalf} + u_0 \\
  v_0 \cdot u & = v_0 \cdot u_{\onehalf} \\
  f\partial^{[1]} - \partial^{[0]} & = -\tfrac{1}{2} u_{\onehalf} \\ 
\shortintertext{Therefore,}
  w_{\onehalf} & = -2 f \partial^{[1]} + 2 \partial^{[0]}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but i’d also recommend `u_{-1/2}`

Comment: @egreg - I was thinking about just this issue as well! I decided not to mention the  `u_{-1/2}` possibility in my answer, as I have no idea whether or not it's important to write `_{-\frac{1}{2}}` instead of `_{-1/2}`. (I felt safe about the `\smash[t]` idea, though...) Maybe somebody with deeper knowledge of physics-related typographical practice will weigh in with some more information on this. :-)